# Group multiple condition logic with CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, grouping, multiple-conditions

I need to run a query with conditions of `where` and `or_where` using CodeIgniter. The code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('registration');
$this->db->where('MemberStatus', 1);
$this->db->where('Gender', $gender);

if(!empty($city))
    $this->db->where_in('City', $city);

if(!empty($education_sector))
    $this->db->where_in('education_sector', $education_sector);

if(!empty($degree))
    $this->db->where_in('Education', $degree);

$this->db->or_where_in('Education1', $degree);
```

The above code creates a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`registration`)
WHERE `MemberStatus` = 1
    AND `Gender` = '1'
    AND (Age BETWEEN "18" AND "30")
    AND `Education` IN ('BCom', 'MCom')
    OR `Education1` IN ('BCom', 'MCom')
```

If the `or_where` clause is satisfied, then the other conditions are not respected. How can I group the conditions referencing `$degree`?

Comment: I find your question to be ambiguous about the exact desired sql.  Please complete this question by expressing the exact sql that you need.  Also, the use of `!empty()` seems inappropriate too.  Why do you check the existence of `$degree` when accessing it the first time, but the second time, you access the variable without any guarantee that the variable exists.  This is strange ...or wrong.  The solution is to use `group_start()` and `group_end()`, but the trouble is that your question is too vague to confidently answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this:

```
if(!empty($gender) || !empty($age) || !empty($city) || !empty($degree) || !empty($education_sector))
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('registration');
    $this->db->where('MemberStatus',1);
    $this->db->where('Gender', $gender);
    $this->db->where($age >= 18);
    $this->db->where($age <= 30);
    $this->db->where_in('City',$city);
    $this->db->where_in('education_sector',$education_sector);
    $this->db->where_in('Education',$degree);
    $this->db->or_where_in('Education1',$degree);
}
```

**Edit - 1:**

This is complicated. You need `UNION` to achieve what you want. Unfortunately, CI Active Records  doesn't support `UNION`, so you'll have to use the `$this->db->query()` function to write your query.

It will be like this:

```
if(!empty($gender) || !empty($age) || !empty($city) || !empty($degree) || !empty($education_sector))
{
    $q = "(SELECT * FROM registration 
    WHERE MemberStatus = 1 
    AND Gender = '$gender'
    AND Age BETWEEN (18,30)
    AND City IN ('$city')
    AND education_sector IN ('$education_sector'))
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM registration
    WHERE Education IN ('$degree')
    OR Education1 IN ('$degree'))";
    $this->db->query($q);
}
```

Comment: actually i need that or_where_in clause should be compare only the previous condition, means the column Education & Education1

Comment: That's what I did, didn' I?

Comment: I do not support these snippets.  The use of multiple `!empty()` checks with `||` means that if _any_ of the variables exist, then the query will be attempted -- but the logic _should_ be the that ALL variables are `!empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would recommend first of the below two solutions:

- Move the logic of this query to the database side. Create a stored procedure and pass all the parameters to it and depending on the values passed to this build the select statement there (with all the columns etc etc) as needed. And from PHP side (from Codeigniter) just call this stored procedure to get what you need.

  Write a raw query in PHP and just use the "query" functionality of Codeigniter.